# Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions. by using middleware

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, middleware

this is the store.js file

```
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'

import rootReducers from './reducers/index'

import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension'

const store = createStore(
    rootReducers, composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(thunk))
    
   
)

const DataProvider = ({children}) => {
    return(
        <Provider store={store}>
            {children}
        </Provider>
    )
}

export default DataProvider
```

this is the app.js file

```
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route} from 'react-router-dom'
import PageRender from './PageRender';
import Home from './pages/home'
import Login from './pages/login'
import Register from './pages/register'

function App() {
  return (
    
    <Router>
      <input type="checkbox" id= "theme" />
    <div className="App">
      <div className="main">
       <Routes>
       <Route exact path="/" element={<Home/>} />
       <Route exact path="/" element={<Register/>} />
       <Route exact path="/" element={<Login/>} />
        <Route exact path="/:page" element={<PageRender/>} />
        <Route exact path="/:page/:id" element={<PageRender/>} />
        </Routes>
      <h1>Hello Client</h1>
      </div>
    
    </div>
    </Router>
    
  );
}

export default App;
```

src/index.js file

```
import ReactDOMClient from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css'

import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import DataProvider from './redux/store';



const root = ReactDOMClient.createRoot( document.getElementById('root'))

root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
   
    <DataProvider store={'./redux/store'}>
      <App />
      </DataProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
 
);


reportWebVitals();
```

login.js file

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import { login } from '../redux/actions/authAction'
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux'

const Login = () => {
    const initialState = { email: '', password: '' }
    const [userData, setUserData] = useState(initialState)
const { email, password } = userData

const dispatch = useDispatch()


const handleChangeInput = e => {
    const {name, value} = e.target
    setUserData({...userData, [name]: value})
}

const handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    dispatch(login(userData))
}

    return (
        <div className="auth_path">
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
    <h3 className='text-uppercase'>MediaGen</h3>
  <div className="form-group">
    <label htmlFor="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" className="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" 
    aria-describedby="emailHelp" onChange={handleChangeInput} value={email} name="email"/>
    <small id="emailHelp" className="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
  </div>
  <div className="form-group">
    <label htmlFor="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
    <input type="password" className="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" 
    onChange={handleChangeInput} value={password} name="password"/>
  </div>
  
  <button type="submit" className="btn btn-dark w-100"
  disabled={email && password ? false : true}>
      Login
      </button>
      <p className="my-2">
                    You don't have an account? <Link to="/register" style={{color: "crimson"}}>Register Now</Link>
                </p>
</form>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Login
```

I am trying to make a social media app.
But it says  "Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions."
[This is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IT0fI.png)
There is a problem with this.
Please help me to find out.
I cannot understand what is the problem here. please help me. I am a beginner. it says to use middleware

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably coming from here:

```
const handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    dispatch(login(userData))
}
```

You want to either:

- Dispatch an action which is a JavaScript object
- Dispatch a function which gets captured by middleware, that middleware runs its logic and produces an object action.

So you either forgot to use redux-thunk middleware or forgot to return an object from `login` action creator.